# What is the limit to the number of labels in Google Keep?

Tags: google-keep

I cannot add more labels to Google Keep because there seems to be a limit to the amount of labels you can use. I cannot find what that limit is. (I don't think I have used that many labels!) Does anybody know what that limit is?
I think a limit to the number of labels you can use is not logical for a note-taking application.

Answer (score 6):

### The limit seems to be 50.

I created 49 labels, and after creating the 50th, I received a message telling me I had reached the limit.

You could find out how many labels you have, by using the browser developer console. In Chrome, you do that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and run the following statement:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[data-item*="tag"]').length
```

The console will now output the number of tags you have:
[image: The Chrome developer console]

Comment: I have 45 tags and cannot add a new one :( Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

I created 99 labels. It's the limit

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/6r0ylp/what_is_the_current_limit_for_number_of_labels_in/ suggests the number of labels was bumped up to 100 some time around 2017, just after Vidar Ramdal's answer.